# counting a special category in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have following data frame

```
S.No   Description    amount
1      a, b, c        100
2      a, c           50
3      b, c           80
4      b, d           90
5      a              150
```

I want to extract only the counts of a

expected answer:

```
description
a  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) and `sum`:

```
df['Description'].str.count('a').sum()
```

Output: `3`

If you want all the counts:

```
df['Description'].str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
a    3
b    3
c    3
d    1
Name: Description, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `split` with `explode` then `value_counts`

```
s = df.Description.str.split(', ').explode().value_counts()
s['a']
```

Or we do

```
s = df.Description.str.split(', ',expand=True).eq('a').sum().sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.Description.str.count("a").sum()
```

Output:    3